# jQuery get submitted form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 form and this forms have same input field (same names)

```
$("#first-form, #second-form").submit(function(event) {

$('#name').val()

});
```

In my example I get first form input value, I need to get submited form value.

I also trgu use  `$(this)('#name').val()` but this method not work.

How to get submited form input values, if I have 2 same forms.

Comment: What about `.serialize()` ?

Comment: I think you have got to use ajax/php for this one.

Comment: If you've got duplicated form fields in both forms, they cannot possibly be called #name as that's an ID, and IDs are unique.

Comment: According to your JS, both inputs have the same ID, not (only) the same name. IDs should never occur twice on a page.

Comment: @bodruk Really depends what they want to do with the value(s). If it's just to submit via an AJAX request, `.serialize()` would be exactly what they need. If they want to do some client-side validation of entered values then it wouldn't be much use at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    $(this).find('[name=yourfieldsname]').val();
});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It would, though the `.each()` function is unnecessary. The `.submit(fn)` function for setting up an event handler will iterate over the selected elements itself.

Comment: this example work, but i have problem with `$(this).find("input[name='"+value+"']").prop('disabled', true)` why this not work ?

Comment: Can you give some context? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I try disable input of this field

Answer (score 1):

```
        $("#first-form, #second-form").submit(function(event) {
            $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+' #name').val();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've corrected the issue of (apparently) having duplicated IDs, you can select the input with a given name only inside the form that's been submitted like so:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var name = $('[name="name"]', this).val();
});
```

Inside the `submit` event handler `this` refers to the form that triggered the event (i.e. the form being submitted), and `$(selector, element)` is equivalent to `$(element).find(selector)` which searches only inside of element for elements matching the selector.